# waAgent integration on custom Linux :- Troubleshoot interaction between waAgent and Fabric

Tags: linux, azure

I am trying to integrate waagent in our custom linux based on centos 6.5
At present, I can upload vhd image of my custom linux and deploy it on Azure without waagent
I can connect to this VM in Azure using SSH
But since waagent is not integrated, Azure will show deployment status as as "Deploying" for long time and finally changes the status to "Failed"

So decided to integrate waagent to my customized Linux. 
waAgent is also required as I need to publish my image in the Azure Market Place.
Since my VM is customized, I cannot simply install waAgent and start using it
Wherever waAgent has a chance to fail, I modified waAgent code in such a way that it won't fail and send success message to Fabric

Once my new VM (VM with waAgent) is deployed in Azure, I will manually connect to it using ssh and start waagent. 
Through tcpdump, I verified that waagent is sending message to Azure Fabric that VM provisioning is "succeeded". 
But still Azure portal does not change status from "Provisioning" to "Succeeded"

To proceed further I thought I need to find out what is missing in the communication between waAgent and Azure Fabric.
But there is no easy way to get tcpdump of success case so that I can compare the success tcpdump with my failure tcpdump. 
Following are the options are tried to get tcpdump of success case.

1. Deployed Centos image from market place. 
   Since there is no way to start tcpdump before waAgent triggers, I followed this way.
   Connect to VM using SSH
   Ran "waagent -deprovision",
   Now start tcpdump and run "waagent --daemon"
   But waAgent fails to mount CD rom as Azure provides CD ROM during boot time only
2. Use 'user defined routes' to divert traffic from one VM to another VM.
   This way traffic between waagent and fabric can be captured in another VM for a success case
   But 'user defined routes' do not divert traffic to another machine if packets are designated to Azure Fabric
3. Thought to have Azure stack in data center so that both client and Fabric is in my control. 
   But learnt that protocol that is used in Azure stack is not same as that of Azure

Questions

1. How I can get tcp dump for success case tcpdump of waAgent so that I can compare the my failure case tcpdump with it
2. If I am not in the right direction, what is the easy way integrate waAgent in customized OS versions ?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

> If I am not in the right direction, what is the easy way integrate
>   waAgent in customized OS versions ?

Azure supports install waagent on CentOS 6.5. More information about prepare a CentOS-based virtual machine for Azure please refer to this [official article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-create-upload-centos#centos-6x).